# Apache Cordova - hooking into native lifecycle methods

Tags: cordova

I am studying the feasibility of migrating a WebView app currently implemented separately in iOS and Android to a Cordova solution. As well as the WebView which is used to present our main JS/HTML app, there are various bits of functionality in our native code, such as integrating 3rd party libraries for push messaging, recording events and data or tracking, as well as code to detect various URL changes, act on back button presses, reading a local config file, etc.

I'm in fairly early stages of knowledge with Cordova, and understand the plugin architecture allows us to communicate from the Javascript part of the Cordova app to Native.

However, how would I (for example on the Android side) do things that are currently done in the app's onCreate() method, such as initialising certain cloud messaging services, or that are done in certain Activities onNewIntent() methods, etc?

I've not written any exploratory code yet, but wondered if anyone knows of documentation that explains how you'd go about it, or any examples of Cordova apps that have been customized in this way? I think we would prefer this to be a CLI project but from what little I understand this level of customization would need 2 different Platform-centered projects? Is it possible to achieve this in a CLI project with plugins?

Comment: First of all your question is very very broad. But to start off, i feel it should be possible with plugins and some plugins are readily available for push messaging. For custom plugins, you have to start off from here - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was just me being a newb, I now know I can subclass android Application and tie that in to the plug in. A little bit complex but at least there are examples out there

Comment: Should i post it as an answer?